# Programatically change post author

Tags: author, wp-update-post

Given a user id, $user_id, and post id, $post_id, how can I programatically update a wordpress post author?

Note: these posts are already created and the author cannot be set upon creation. Another process is creating the post and defaulting to the admin as the author. I don't have access to creating the post but have access after it is created.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It shouldn't be any problem. Try this:

```
$arg = array(
    'ID' => $post_id,
    'post_author' => $user_id,
);
wp_update_post( $arg );
```

Comment: this ends up with the post having the user as its author, but if you try to query a users posts it returns nothing - it seems that the user doesn't know about the post when it has been authored that way. It also means that when you delete the user the posts don't get deleted, as they are queried from the deleted user

Comment: @AbrahamBrookes what you mentioned didn't happen in my case. couldn't confirm :)

Answer (score -2):

you can also just add another admin account. delete the one that's authoring the posts and WP will ask where to assign posts. Choose preferred author, done.

Comment: Note that the requirement is _programmatically_.