# Change post author without using wp_update_post()

Tags: posts, post-meta, author, save-post

The standard or more obvious way to change a post author in WP is to use the [wp_update_post()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_post/) function, as shown in [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/186253/programatically-change-post-author).

But I am having an issue, described as follows:

```
// Inside the save_post attached callback

$arg = array(
    'ID' => $post_id,
    'post_author' => $whoever,
);
wp_update_post($arg); --> This fires the save_post hook --> Infinite loop
```

This is a special case in which I need to do the update inside the *save_post* callback. This results in an infinite loop. (See [this similar case](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33352/using-wp-update-post-on-save-post))

I wonder if there is an alternative way to update a post author that does not fire the *save_post* hook.

I know I could use the builtin author metabox for this, but the requirements push me to not use the builtin author metabox, and I must use a custom metabox to update the post author.

A possible solution is using SQL directly:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts`
SET `post_author` = 2
WHERE `ID` = 1
```

Which could be implemented with:

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->get_results("UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_author` = " . $int_author . " WHERE `ID` = " . $int_ID);
```

Of course previously making sure that both variables contain numbers.

Does anybody know a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the few occasions when I've needed to do something similar, I've used the callback *unattach-update-reattach* method, which is also described on this older Q&A, [Update post on save](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/246957/update-post-on-save) and on the [developer docs comments](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_post/#comment-843).

```
function your_save_post_callback( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
    // unattach the callback
    remove_action('save_post', 'your_save_post_callback');

    // update post
    wp_update_post( $args );

    // reattach the callback
    add_action('save_post', 'your_save_post_callback');
}
```